# MSAccess - Design query to group by anniversary date

Tags: ms-access

Lets say I have a table with these fields

```
LeaveDate
LeaveType
```

I want to write a query  that groups by an annivesary date.

For example say 8th Feb.

So for this year any dates after 8 Feb would be "2010" and any dates before 8 Feb would show "2009".

I want this to occur for all years data.

Understand??

Malcolm

Comment: Sounds like you'd want to do a datediff from the first anniversary date, then take the floor of the result in years, then group by that.  Never used Access for non-trivial database work, though, so couldn't advise you *how* to do it.

Comment: Oh, also, if you want a helpful response, it'd be best to post the definition of the relevant table(s) and an example of what you'd expect the output of the query to look like.

Comment: Ah, same name for the function as everywhere else: DateDiff() http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access/ha012288111033.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I did it

```
SELECT Year([tblFoo]![Leave_date])-IIf(DateDiff("d",[tblFoo]![Leave_date],DateSerial(Year([tblFoo]![Leave_date]),2,8))>0,1,0) AS Year_group, Count(tblFoo.ID) AS CountOfID

FROM tblFoo

GROUP BY Year([tblFoo]![Leave_date])-IIf(DateDiff("d",[tblFoo]![Leave_date],DateSerial(Year([tblFoo]![Leave_date]),2,8))>0,1,0);
```

This counts the number of records for each “Year”. We use something similar for working out birthday years which change from person to person. In that case use can just replace the fixed 2 and 8 with the month and day they were born

Answer (score 0):

You could create a query with a calculated column for anniversary date, then group by that column.